# Where are all the files I can #import in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, import, header

I'm working in Xcode. Where are all the header and libraries I can link with my projects? What directory? I want to find archives like these and discover others I have never found...

objc-runtime.h
math.h

Thanks. Sorry I know It's too easy.

Comment: please read this article, it should help http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/01/helping-xcode-find-library-headers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other *BSD, on MacOS the default location for header files is in in /usr/include. To find all headers that may or may not be in the include path of your compiler, you could also use this command in a shell:

```
find / -name "*.h"
```